# Wordpress slideshow plugin error

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a plugin called Skitter fo WP..its a slideshow jQuery plugin.

For some reason im getting

> Error loading images. One or more images were not found.

I recently transfered my website from one host to another..copying all the files. now its not working, needless to say it worked before the transfer..no files were changed in any manner what so ever..only wp-config file for db etc'..

I tried the solution offered here -

> https://github.com/thiagosf/SkitterSlideshow/issues/7

But it didn't worked..

The wp settings of the plugin are the same as they were with my images attached to the plugin.

The website is

> www.tranceil.fm

Any thoughts?

Comment: A new domain (as per @Lipins answer) or just a different server? My money is on directory permissions.

Comment: different server m8..any advice on what folder to change permissions to?

Comment: I dont know the plugin - check the backup you made, which directory are the images for the slider? In the uploads directory probably but not necessarily.

Comment: Just guessing without link - it isn't using timthumb to resize the images is it? If it is then it's the permissions on the cache directory.

Comment: I dont know if its timbthumb but i do know its cropping them yes...where is that cache folder? change to 777? www.tranceil.fm

Comment: Well it would be called cache and it would probably be in the skitter plugins folder - but now I've looked at your link I'm not convinced  that's the issue to be honest. Sorry, at least we've ruled some things out.

Comment: yup..well i appreciate your help anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

A quick thought gone through my mind: The error was just happened when you transfer your website. Let me explain.

I believe you uploaded the slider images using WordPress Image Uploader. So your image's address will be like this: `www.youroldsite.com/wp-content/wp-uploads/2012/08/slider1.jpg`

When you transfer your website to another domain, WordPress will not update these locations. So simply when the plugin checks for above address, it is unavailable.

**Solution:**

- You need to change the slider image's URL manually or
- Delete all slides and Re-upload the images again on your new host.

Comment: thanx for the reply buddy. well its the same domain name just a changed server..and just to play it safe i reuploaded one of the pic and reassigned it in the skitter plugin settings..it didn't worked either.. :(

Comment: Try this: Go to `Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalinks` and simply click the `Save Changes` button one or two times. Then check your website again.